# Python sending files from a user directory to another user directory

Tags: python

I am very new to Python. I am curious to how I would be able to copy some files from my directory to another Users directory on my computer using python script? And would I be correct in saying I need to check the permissions of the users and files? So my question is how do I send files and also check the permissions at the same time

Comment: You can try it, though it might fail. But you can write code to handle the failures.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `shutil.copy(src, destination)`, you can find the docs here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy

You can also read here on how to access file permissions in python: [Checking File Permissions in Linux with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861836/checking-file-permissions-in-linux-with-python)

[Determining Whether a Directory is Writeable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113427/determining-whether-a-directory-is-writeable)

Answer (score 1):

shutil is a very usefull thing to use when copying files.
I once needed to have a python script that moved all .mp3 files from a directory to a backup, deleted the original directory, created a new once, and moved the .mp3 files back in. shutil was perfect for thise.

The formatting for the command is how @Kieran has stated earlier.

If you're looking to keep file metadata, then use shutil.copy2(src, dest), as that is the equivalent of running copy() and copystat() one after another.