# python os.listdir hitting OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-os

I'm trying to use os.listdir to grab a list of subdirectories but am running into an issue when I'm lacking permissions for one of these subdirectories. I can *not* gain permission so I'd like to continue as gracefully as possible. Ideally, I'd be able to ignore any directory I do not have permission to and return any others so as to not miss any child directories.

I've tried using os.walk but I ran into a number of other issues (performance included) and have decided not to use it.

An example. In the root directory there are 3 children, a, b, c

```
root dir
|
----> dir a 
|
----> dir b
|
----> dir c
```

I have permissions to a and c but not b (not known ahead of time). I'd like to return [a, c]

Here's the code with some generalizations-

```
def get_immediate_subdirectories(directory):
"""Returns list of all subdirectories in
directory

Args:
  directory: path to directory

Returns:
  List of child directories in directory excluding 
  directories in exclude and any symbolic links

"""
exclude = ["some", "example", "excluded", "dirnames"]
sub_dirs = []
try:
    all_files = os.listdir(directory)
except OSError:
    # **Ideally I'd be able to recover some list here/continue**
for name in all_files:
    if name in exclude:
        continue
    full_path = os.path.join(directory, name)
    if os.path.isdir(full_path):
        # Keep these separate to avoid issue
        if not os.path.islink(full_path):
            sub_dirs.append(name)
return sub_dirs
```

Comment: `listdir()` doesn't fail when it hits an individual file you can't read -- it only fails when you don't have `+r` on the directory you're reading itself, or `+x` on its parents; the permissions of the files or directories within are irrelevant.

Comment: ...so, if you get an OSError from `os.listdir()`, then there's nothing to recover -- if you don't have `+r` on the directory, you have no access to read *any* of its contents.

Comment: With respect to the `os.path.isdir()` and `os.path.islink()`, btw, those both use only the syscall `stat(2)`; on MacOS, the only way that can cause `EACCES` is if a component of the path to the directory *holding* the file doesn't have `+x` -- so if you had `+r` but not `+x` on the directory, then the `listdir()` would succeed, but the `os.path.isdir()` on its contents would fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption made in this question -- that a non-readable entry partway through a directory can cause `os.listdir()` to fail, and that a partial result consisting of other entries is possible -- is false.

Observe:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.mkdir('unreadable.d')
>>> os.chmod('unreadable.d', 0)
>>> result = os.listdir('.')
>>> print result
['unreadable.d']
```

It's only trying to run `listdir()` on the unreadable directory itself that fails:

```
>>> os.listdir('unreadable.d')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'unreadable.d'
```

Comment: So it's safe to say that if I ever encounter this error I can handle it by doing something as simple as returning an empty list

Comment: Thanks! I was only looking here [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) and didn't think to look at how it really handles the permissions

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's stopping you from catching the exception and handling it there (e.g. by doing `return []` or `continue`)?

Answer (score 0):

Walk the directory, and check if you have access first:

```
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk('/path/to/folder'):
    for dir in dirnames:
        path = os.path.join(dirpath, dir)
        read_write = os.access(path, os.W_OK) and os.access(path, os.R_OK)
        # W_OK write True and R_OK read True
        if not read_write:
            continue
```

See: [Determining Whether a Directory is Writeable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113427/determining-whether-a-directory-is-writeable)

Comment: `os.walk()` is using the same syscall `os.listdir()` does -- though it will just not return anything it can't read silently rather than throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the ownership of the files:

```
$ sudo chown -R <userwhorunpython>:<userwhorunpython> <yourdirectory>
```

If it doesn't work, run a:

```
$ sudo chmod -r 777 directory
```

Check the `chmod` and `chown` manual for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `PermissionError` exception

```
try:
    os.listdir('path/to/folder')
except PermissionError:
    # do something else
```